# When should I call createIndex in mongodb in a nodejs environment?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, server

I am wondering when I have to call createIndex:
1- each time I connect or start the db
2- after inserting and updating documents
3- before making queries

I don't know exactly when.
Also if createIndex is called one time, is the index stored on the RAM or the disk?

UPDATED
How does the option autoindex in mongoose work?
According to the docs I should set it to false in production so how can I index my db?

Answer (score 0):

You want to have indexes in place before querying.

Indexes are stored on disk and loaded into memory as necessary.

Comment: of course, they need to be in place before any query but where should i call createIndex exaclty ?

Comment: There is no requirement that it is called from anywhere in particular. Do what you like.

Comment: in the docs is mentioned that calling it has an impact on the performance so I should call it as less as possible

Comment: You should call it once.